# every cauchy sequentially regular function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ be any metric spaces and $f:(X,d)\to (Y,e)$ be a cauchy sequentially regular function (that maps cauchy sequencees to cauchy). Then, how to prove that f is continuous.

Comment: You prove that it's sequentially continuous (which is equivalent to being continuous for metric spaces). A convergent sequence $x_n \to x_\ast$ is Cauchy, so it is mapped to a Cauchy sequence. Now, to show that $f(x_n) \to f(x_\ast)$, consider modifying $(x_n)$ by intertwining it with a special sequence.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence. Show that if $x_n\to x$ then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, and conclude that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The main problem which I was facing is the codomain is not given to be complete.

Comment: @manisha: Yes, that is a problem. But what happens when you modify $x_n$ by defining $x'_n=\begin{cases} x_n & n=2k\\ x& n=2k+1\end{cases}$?

Comment: Lemma: a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence converges to the limit of the subsequence.